# VSTO outlook 2013 add-in: is it possible to connect to a RESTful web-api?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, outlook, vsto

I have a hosted web application with Web-API 2 and I have a VSTO Outlook 2013 add-in.

Is it possible to connect the Outlook add-in to a RESTful Web-API?

A user must be able to login inside of the Add-in and the Add-in itself needs access to the business logic on the web server.

Or do I need to realize the Outlook add-in with the new Office365 approach? Which is basically a web application and html/css/js. In that case a connection to a RESTful api seems a lot easier. My Outlook add-in needs to support 2013 and 2016. Does the new approach supports Outlook 2013?

Comment: Further to Alex's answer: just use HttpWebRequest in .NET to send REST calls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to a RESTful Web-API, and even more, from your vsto addin you can do everything you can do in usual windows applications, with very small restrictions. Office 365 approach allows you to connect, too, but it has many restrictions, similar to webpages. Upside is that it is more crossplatform, it's not restricted to Windows/x86, but works or will work in future in other platforms.